# Why does the LinkedList mutable iterator not have a `remove_next` method?

Tags: rust

I want an `O(1)` delete of the node in the [`LinkedList::IterMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/collections/linked_list/struct.IterMut.html).`Vec` or other can't.

Comment: At a cursory glance, a good number of methods could be thought of as "missing"; the most probable reason is that nobody implemented them yet... if this is not what you were asking for, then could you please specify your question?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Yes, "nobody implemented them yet" or "for some reason, nobody implemented them"

Comment: There is no O(1) delete on LinkedList. If you used it in iterator, it cost you to iterate to that point. Further more [Vec#swap_remove](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/collections/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.swap_remove), does O(1) delete without preserving ordering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely reason as to why there isn't a `remove_next` method, is because Rust team is evaluating cursors as alternative approach:

```
#[inline]
#[unstable(feature = "collections",
           reason = "this is probably better handled by a cursor type -- we'll see")]
```

[[Source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/collections/linked_list/struct.IterMut.html#method.insert_next/linked_list.rs.html#786-789)]